# unblockUI of jquery.blockUI freeze in the second call

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-blockui

My first call of ajax'sBlockUI is OK ( block and unblock). But in the second time the blockUI freeze. I need to refresh the page (F5) and after that the page unfreeze.
I don't undersand Why the code work in first time and not in second call

```
<script>

         $(document).ajaxStop( setTimeout( $.unblockUI,2000));

         $(document).ready(function() {
          var map = new Object();   
            //pour chaque div possedant lattribut class
            $( 'div[class]').each(function(index){}).draggable( 
                {   
                    //l'evenement stop correspond fin du drag
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        var position = $(this).position();
                        map[this.id] = position;        
                }, 
                    // permet de delimiter la zone 
                    containment: "#content"}).click(function() {
                    alert('test');
            });


            $('#savePosition').click(function() {

            var allPosition='';
                for (var m in map){
                allPosition+= m +'-' + map[m].top + '-' + map[m].left+'/';
                }
                  $.blockUI({ css: { 
                        border: 'none', 
                        padding: '15px', 
                        backgroundColor: '#000', 
                        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                        '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                        opacity: .5, 
                        color: '#fff' 
                    }, message: 'Sauvegarde en cours du dispositif' }); 


                 var updateUserRoute = #{jsRoute @Application.saveDisposition() /}

                 callAjax(updateUserRoute,allPosition);

            });     
        });

        function callAjax(updateUserRoute,allPosition){

                $.ajax({
                 url: updateUserRoute.url(),
                 type: updateUserRoute.method,
                 data:{ positionTables: allPosition}
                });

                //.done(function( msg ) {
             // alert( "disposition des tables sauvegardé" );
            //  });
        }




        </script>
```